# Increase width of dropdown to make long values fully visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using [Select2](https://select2.github.io). So far all good but I am getting the following behavior with a `SELECT` turned on a `Select2`.

[image]

By behavior I mean the SELECT doesn't increase to it's larger element so I am seeing them as the image above shows. I have read [here](https://select2.github.io/options.html) and [here](https://select2.github.io/options-old.html) but nothing is helpful at all there. Also I have found [this](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/996) but I don't now where that `dropdownAutoWidth` property is or if it's alive.

Any advice? Is this possible? How?

Comment: Can you inspect this element in your browser? It looks to be inheriting width from the parent element

Comment: @NathanFoss the parent element is a LI without width. This LI is expanding dynamic based on it's children element

Comment: Hi @ReynierPM It's working take a look here [select2 Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/b5bugepp/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by setting min-width to .select2-dropdown

Comment: I don't know if this is the way to go since the CSS is set on page render and the SELECT is transformed into a Select2 after page render by Javascript. I could set that value from Javascript as well but I don't think this is a good way

Comment: CSS rules will applied to element anyway.